# How to move tracks from one foobar2000 playlist to another?

Tags: music, playlists, foobar2000, music-management

I like to maintain several playlists in foobar2000, moving entire albums from one playlist to another. I typically do this by selecting an album and using `Utilities -> Send to playlist...` to select the new playlist. I then need to go back to the old playlist, and remove the album from there.

I would like to get rid of this last step, "cutting and pasting" the tracks instead of "copying" them. Is there any context menu item or component that would allow me to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you select a group of songs you will be able to click and drag the songs to a new playlist.  This will have the behaviour that you have seen.

Instead of using the left mouse button to click and drag the songs you should use the right mouse button to drag the new songs to the new playlist. If you drop it on the name of the playlist you will get a context menu with the option `Copy here + remove from the source playlist`

[image]

The trick here is to release the right mouse button *before* it changes playlist.  If you do not release the mouse button soon enough then it will not remove the files from the source playlist.

[image]

Right clicking and dragging to a specific place within the new playlist will give you a context menu with a `Move here` option, but this will **not** remove it from the old playlist.

Answer (score 4):

Apart from [Mokubai's answer](https://superuser.com/a/828548/114046), keyboard shortcuts `Ctrl + X` and `Ctrl + V` also work as expected for cutting and pasting songs from one playlist to another.